# Dynamic Linq Order By Variable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that I am writing some `C#` `selenium` automation for and need some help using Dynamic Linq. Let's say I have a basic `AcctNum`, `AcctDate` and `AcctName` record and each field can be sorted by the user. They could choose `AcctNum` (asc), `AcctDate`(asc) and finally `AcctName` (asc).

That would be:

```
 var sortedCode = records.OrderBy(r => r.AcctNum)
                         .ThenBy(r => r.AcctDate)
                         .ThenBy(r => r.AcctName)
                         .ToList();
```

However the user could also choose `AcctNum` (desc), `AcctDate`(asc) and finally `AcctName` (desc).

What I would like to do is use Dynamic Linq and make each sort order a variable.

So something like:

```
 //passed in values:
 var varAcctNumOrd = "desc";
 var varDateOrd = "asc";
 var varAcctOrd = "desc";

 var sortedCode = records.OrderBy(r => r.AcctNum, varAcctNumOrd)
                         .ThenBy(r => r.AcctDate, varDateOrd)
                         .ThenBy(r => r.AcctNum, varAcctOrd)
                         .ToList();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking for dynamic direction (ascending/descending) or the fields also are dynamic? And btw, so called Dynamic LINQ (`System.Linq.Dynamic`) works with strings.

Comment: Hey Ivan. The test case will pass a variable for ascending or descending order for each field. I just need to pass each of those variables to the sort order so I van validate the sorts are working correctly in the UI.

Comment: And what is the **type** of the `records` variable - `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Right now records is IEnumerable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following simple custom extension methods should do the job:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        bool ascending)
    {
        return ascending ? source.OrderBy(keySelector) : source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> ThenBy<TSource, TKey>(
        this IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        bool ascending)
    {
        return ascending ? source.ThenBy(keySelector) : source.ThenByDescending(keySelector);
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source,
        Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector,
        bool ascending)
    {
        return ascending ? source.OrderBy(keySelector) : source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> ThenBy<TSource, TKey>(
        this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source,
        Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector,
        bool ascending)
    {
        return ascending ? source.ThenBy(keySelector) : source.ThenByDescending(keySelector);
    }
}
```

And the usage will be:

```
//passed in values:
var varAcctNumOrd = "desc";
var varDateOrd = "asc";
var varAcctOrd = "desc";

var sortedCode = records.OrderBy(r => r.AcctNum, varAcctNumOrd != "desc")
                        .ThenBy(r => r.AcctDate, varDateOrd != "desc")
                        .ThenBy(r => r.AcctNum, varAcctOrd != "desc")
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan and everyone else. I appreciate the quick replies. I will take a look and see if I can digest all of this :).

Comment: Ivan I think the first static needs to be   public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByWithDirection<TSource, TKey>
         (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,

Comment: @Dazed Right, thank you! (and sorry, I did it for `IQueryable<T>`, then copy/pasted/adjusted for `IEnumerable<T>` and missed that).

Comment: Appreciate the help on this one. Worked well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to handle a dynamic ordering for your collection according each column and direction (i.e. AcctNum desc)

I'm agree with Ivan Stoev, that kind of linq works with strings not with typed classes.

You can solve this issue using AsQueryable() solution.

Answer (score 0):

Until the `ToList` is called one is building a query thanks to the `IQueryable` interface. Simply have some Booleans to determine direction and do the ordering as such:

```
var recordsToSort = records.AsQueryable();

if (isByAcctNum)
{
   recordsToSort = recordsToSort.OrderBy(r => r.AcctNum);

   if (isByDate)
      recordsToSort =  recorsToSort.ThenBy(r => r.AcctDate)

   ....
}
else
{
    ....

}

return recordsToSort.ToList()
```

You need to put in the precedence logic of the primary sort for the first `OrderBy` call then each secondary `ThenBy` calls. Which I leave up to you, I don't know the data.